# bash: npm: command not found in cPanel Terminal

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, cpanel, whm

I get response, When try to write:

```
$ /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/npm -v
8.1.2
```

but with :

```
$ npm -v
bash: npm: command not found
```

So, I tried as the same logic but it didn't work:

```
$ /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/mydomain/public_html/app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mydomain/public_html/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mydomain/.npm/_logs/2022-03-02T14_43_55_155Z-debug.log
```

So, how to make " npm " command lines works on server.

Comment: The error message looks clear in this case. Your currently directory doesn't have a `package.json` file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First install NodeJS install on cPanel, WHM.

To install NodeJS from WHM, Goto **Home /
Software /
EasyApache 4**

And in Additional Packages find NodeJS.

[image]

After that create an environment variable which points to the node directory.
Run this command to do that.

```
export PATH=/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/:$PATH
```

Finally run `npm -v` to check NodeJS version.

Hope this will help for someone.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create an environment variable which points to the right directory. This should do the job:

```
export PATH=/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/:$PATH
```

or add it to your `.bashrc` file to keep it persistent. And regarding this npm error you get, as jordanm mentioned you don't have `package.json` file in you current directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the path inside in your `.bashrc` file. You can do it easily by run following command.

```
echo export PATH=/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/:$PATH
```